# How to consume a graphql API with Vue

Tags: vuejs2, graphql, apollo, vue-apollo

Pretty simple you'd think given the popularity of both, but I am encountering a few hurdles.

I am using scaphold.io to be able to quickly show off a working UI. That is, if Vue can interact with Scaphold.

I have investigated two resources:

https://github.com/kristianmandrup/vue2-apollo-scaphold

Which seems to be a Scaphold production. Tried it. Many, many vague bugs.

Then there is also:

https://github.com/Akryum/vue-apollo

But this is too much. I don't need a server, the server is on Scaphold.

I also tried building the whole thing up by using the tutorial on howtographql, but this one is also outdated.

Ideally I want to instantiate an as up to date Vue 2 app using (I guess) the npm vue-cli, then install only the required apollo (or whatever, but I guess apollo) add-ons that I need. The minimum.

Shouldn't be too hard, I'll figure it out eventually, but some help is more than welcome.

Answer (score 0):

You can consume a graphql api using your favorite regular request module (ajax, fetch, axios). Take the [scalphold docs](https://scaphold.io/docs/?javascript#queries) for example, but in the callback do `this.vueUserData = body.data.getUser;`
instead of
`console.log(JSON.stringify(body, null, 2));`

(edited to add one gotcha I remembered: if you encounter a problem where the callback doesn't know that `this` is supposed to be the component, you can do `var self = this` before the request function, then reference `self.vueUserData` instead.)

Comment: I found out that https://github.com/kristianmandrup/vue2-apollo-scaphold actually does work, so note that! It needs a lot of tweaking after though, but registering does work right out-of-the-box. I'll report later on, better more up to date answers are still welcome.